# How to route in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Well, having the following in my `routing_dev.yml`

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

homepage:
    pattern:   /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Ideup:index }

aboutme:
    pattern:   /aboutme
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Ideup:about }

_ideup:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/IdeupController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /ideup

_form:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/FormController.php"
    type:     annotation

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

I'm trying to have a simple form:

```
<form action="{{ path('_form') }}" method="POST" id="contact_form">
```

But I keep getting this following exception: `"Route "_form" does not exist."`

I just don't know where else to look and what to do, any ideas?

Comment: Some tips:  (1) I suggest using the `_` for private routes, routes which you don't want people to access on their normal visited but only when you use something like getting the 5 latest blogposts, and remove the `_` for public routes.  (2) You have 2 routes for the `/` path, remove one  (3) Use an underscore to seperate words in routes (`about_me`)  (4) place it in `routing.yml`, the `_dev` file is only loaded if you are in a development environment (read more on environments [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_form:
  resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/FormController.php"
  type:     annotation
```

This will just load annotated routes from the FormController.

For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my/route", name="my_route")
 */
public function myRouteAction() { ... }
```

If you want a `_form` route, you should either load all annotationed routes from the FormController or define it in another way:

```
_form:
  pattern: /path/to/your/form
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Form:myFormAction }
```

Of course `myFormAction()` should exist in the `FormController`.

Comment: Ok, so what other ways are there to do it? Without `annotations`, if possible

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. Refer to for example `homepage` route in your .yml.